# Setting future date in Java 8

Tags: java-8, zoneddatetime

In Joda we have setCurrentMillisFixed method which can be used to set future date
In one my test cases , i pass a DateTime (joda) parameter to 
 current system time:
`DateTime created = new DateTime()`

`DateTimeUtils.setCurrentMillisSystem(created.toInstant().toEpochMilli()););`

In Java 8 i am trying :
I pass ZonedDateTime instead of DateTime,

I tried setting the date as below:

`ZonedDateTime.now(Clock.fixed(Instant.now().plusMillis(created.toInstant().toEpochMilli()),ZoneId.systemDefault()));`

But lot of test cases are failing, i am guessing this has something to do with how the date is being set.

Any advice ? Could not find any useful piece of code ,

Comment: It could help if you provide some information on why the test cases are failing, or are you asking us to guess as well?

Comment: i am also trying to debug why the tests are failing, code base is pretty huge, i believe somewhere n the code base, the future date is not set, i reverted the chnge to dateTime, it started working again, just wanted to know the correct way to set future date, if we are setting a exact date, i know `DateTimeUtils.setCurrentMillisFixed(new DateTime(1900, 1, 13, 0, 0).getMillis());
` - we can replace with
`Clock clock = Clock.fixed(LocalDateTime.of(1900, 1, 13, 0, 0).toInstant(UTC), systemDefault())`.

Answer (score 3):

## Year 2066?

I suspect you are setting an unintended moment, around 50 years in the future.

Let’s unpack your code.

```
ZonedDateTime.now(                    // Represents a moment adjusted into a time zone. 
    Clock.fixed(
        Instant.now()                 // Get current moment. Actually a count of nanoseconds since 1970-01-01T00:000Z. That is 48 years, about 5 decades worth of nanoseconds.
               .plusMillis(           // Adding some more milliseconds, for a moment in the future, later than now.   
            created.toInstant()       // Accessing some stored moment. Presumably a contemporary date-time.
                   .toEpochMilli()) , // Getting the count of milliseconds since 1970-01-01T00:000Z, another 5 decades or so of time.
            ZoneId.systemDefault()    // Getting the JVM’s current default time zone. To be assigned to our resulting `ZonedDateTime` object.
        )
)
```

So you start with about 5 decades of nanoseconds. Then, presumably, you add approximately another 5 decades of milliseconds. So you end up with a date fifty years in the future, around the year 2066. Is that the value you intended to test?

> 2066 ≈ 2018 + ( time elapsed from 1970 to some moment around 2018 )

We can try that code, so see the result.

```
ZonedDateTime created = ZonedDateTime.of( 2018 , 1 , 23 , 12 , 34 , 56, 0 , ZoneId.systemDefault()); // 2018-01-23T12:34:56 in America/Los_Angeles.

ZonedDateTime zdt =     ZonedDateTime.now(                    // Represents a moment adjusted into a time zone.
    Clock.fixed(
        Instant.now()                 // Get current moment. Actually a count of nanoseconds since 1970-01-01T00:000Z. That is 48 years, about 5 decades worth of nanoseconds.
            .plusMillis(           // Adding some more milliseconds, for a moment in the future, later than now.
                created.toInstant()       // Accessing some stored moment. Presumably a contemporary date-time.
                    .toEpochMilli()) , // Getting the count of milliseconds since 1970-01-01T00:000Z, another 5 decades or so of time.
        ZoneId.systemDefault()    // Getting the JVM’s current default time zone. To be assigned to our resulting `ZonedDateTime` object.
    )
);

System.out.println("created.toString: " + created );
System.out.println("zdt.toString(): " + zdt );
```

Sure enough, year 2066, if `created` is a moment earlier this year.

> created.toString: 2018-01-23T12:34:56-08:00[America/Los_Angeles]
>
> zdt.toString(): 2066-08-09T08:51:38.488980-07:00[America/Los_Angeles]

### Millis vs nanos

Be aware that the *java.time* classes such as [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) and [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) have a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond). That is much finer than the old legacy classes `java.util.Date` & `Calendar` which use [milliseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millisecond).

### Write simple code

**Tip: Don't write so much into one line of code.** Hard for humans to decipher and to debug/trace. And may be harder for the JVM to optimize. Writing dead-simple lines of code is easier on both humans and machines, generally.

So, let’s break up that code into simple lines.

```
Instant now = Instant.now();  // Current moment in UTC, with a resolution of nanoseconds.
Duration fiveMinutes = Duration.ofMinutes( 5L );  // `Duration` represents a span-of-time unattached to the timeline.
Instant fiveMinutesFromNow = now.plus( fiveMinutes );  // Returns a `Instant`, using our original `Instant` object plus adding some span-of-time.
Clock clock = Clock.fixed( fiveMinutesFromNow , ZoneId.systemDefault() );  // Instantiate a clock frozen at a specific moment about five minutes in the future. This clock does not “tick”, remaining fixed at this one specified moment.
```

Now pass that [`Clock`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Clock.html) object named `clock` to your code being tested.

```
…
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( clock ) ;  // Tells a lie. Reports a moment about five minutes in the future as “now”. Good for testing.
…
```

Try it.

> now.toString(): 2018-07-17T19:22:48.670320Z
>
> fiveMinutesFromNow.toString(): 2018-07-17T19:27:48.670320Z
>
> zdt.toString(): 2018-07-17T12:27:48.670320-07:00[America/Los_Angeles]

Yes, it worked. We see the minute-of-hour as `27` rather than `22`, five minutes in the future.

#### Pass a `Clock` in production.

To run that same code in production, outside your test harness, pass the default `Clock` implementation.

```
Clock clock =  Clock.systemDefaultZone() ;  // Default `Clock` used implicitly in Java if you do not say otherwise.
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: Thanks much, i tried this , gives expected result, so in my case, i can just do 

`Instant now = Instant.now();
Duration duration = Duration.ofMillis( created.toInstant().toEpochMilli() );
Instant instant = now.plus( duration ); 
Clock clock = Clock.fixed( instant , ZoneId.systemDefault() );`
i believe